# Solve $x+y+z = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 8$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, functions, roots, diophantine-equations, factoring

Solve $x+y+z = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 8$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

---

First I tried to transform this equation, substituting $x = 8-y-z$. So I end up with:

$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 8$$
$$(8-y-z)^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 8$$

Using Wolfram Alpha I expanded this equation and tried to factorize it so finally I got:

$$(z-8)(y^2 + y(z-8) - 8z) = 168$$

$z \in \mathbb{Z}$, which implies $z-8$ is an integer implying that the second term is also an integer.

168 has 16 positive divisors and 16 negative, which means there are 32 distinct cases to be looked, which is a painful work and made me abandon this method in search of a better and easier method.

---

Second method I tried is Newton Identities.

We want to find the values for the roots $x,y,z$ of the cubic function: $f(x) = x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$

From the condition we have the following equation:

$$x + y + z = 8 = s_1\text{   and   } x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 8 = s_3$$

Using Newton Identities we obtain the following relations:

$$s_1 + b = 0 \implies b = -8$$

$$s_2 + bs_1 + 2c = 0$$
$$s_2 - 64 + 2c = 0 \implies c = \frac{64 - s_2}{2}$$

$$s_3 + bs_2 + cs_1 + 3d = 0$$
$$8 - 8s_2 + \frac{64 - s_2}{2} \times 8 + 3d = 0$$
$$8 - 8s_2 + 256 - 4s_2 + 3d = 0$$
$$3d - 12s_2 + 264 = 0$$
$$d - 4s_2 + 88 = 0 \implies s_2 = \frac{88+d}{4}$$

Substituting back we have:

$$c = \frac{64 - s_2}{2} = \frac{64 - \frac{88+d}{4}}{2} = \frac{\frac{256 - 88 - d}{4}}{2} = \frac{168 - d}{8}$$

And I'm stuck here, because I know only the ratio between $c$ and $d$, which is a consequence of not knowing the value $s_2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$

Comment: Why abandon the first path for only 32 cases? The discriminant of the other factor to be a square $(z-8)^2+32z=(z+8)^2$. So you get for each value for $z$ solutions for $y=(2z-16\pm(z+8))/2$. These are integers only for even $z$. That cuts down the cases a bit.

Comment: What about $x=-16, y=9, z=15$?

Comment: @ABC Let's say this is a contest problem, would you spend 30 minutes to check every combination? Note that the there are 64 values for y, because of the $\pm$ sign in front of the square root.

Comment: @AxelKemper According to Wolfram Alpha (9,15,-16) and its six permutation are the only integer solution, but any idea how to get those values?

Comment: I have used Microsoft Solver Foundation to get this solution. It took less than a second.

Comment: @AxelKemper Same with Wolfram Alpha, but as much as I know computers aren't allowed on contest.

Comment: See also: [Integer solutions to $x^3+y^3+z^3 = x+y+z = 8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870805).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Calculate $(x-8)(y-8)(z-8)$.

---

There are several ways to do the calculation. Working from the last equation in the first method, observe that the second term can be factorized into $(y-8)(y+z)= -(y-8)(x-8)$, which gives us

> $(x-8)(y-8)(z-8) = -168 $

Use this, along with the factors of 168 and that $x-8+y-8+z-8 = -16$ to greatly restrict the cases you have to look at. For example, as Mark comments, since the sum of 3 numbers is even, so either one of them is even, all all three of them are.

---

Now, if you don't want an 'Wolfram Alpha' expansion of the terms, you could do the expansion yourself, it's not that hard. The way that I arrived at the calculation used the fact that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)( (a+b+c)^2 - 3ab -3bc - 3ca) $

Note that since you want to solve this as a Diophantine equation, using algebraic methods can only get you so far. At some point in time, you must change it into a 'number theoretic way', like analyzing the factors, or gcd of terms.

Comment: Note that $168=XYZ=8\times 3 \times 7$ and $X+Y+Z=-16$ implies either three even numbers, or two odd, one even. There is only one possibility for three even. If two factors are odd, the even factor is divisible by $8$ so the sum or difference of the odds has to be a multiple of $8$.

Comment: Very good answer, significantly cutting the number of cases into a reasonable amount. Just one mistake probably a typo: $(y-8)(y+z) = -(y-8)(x-8)$, not $(y-8)(y+z) = -(y-z)(x-8)$,